# Convex Hull using different Algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Hi I was wondering if the answer for the convex hull given same data points would be the same even if I use different algorithms?

For example, I use Gift Wrap algorithm and Quick Hull? Would the answer be the same?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "convex hull". If it's unique by your definition, then all correctly implemented algorithms will yield the same result. I think the only thing which may differ from definition to definition is whether collinear points on the same side of a polygon are allowed.

Comment: It also depends on your definition "the same". If the input points are in general position, therefore the results must be identical. Now you can assume that to different algorithms return the identical point set, but in different order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I see no reason why not.

Convex hull for a set of points is the **minimal convex set** containing all the data points, and hence must be unique.

If two algorithms give difference answers, (at least) one of them is wrong!